# Need help finding correct SQL Query String

Tags: sql, ms-access

Alright, so I have spent hours trying to figure this out and I'm about to go insane! What I've got is a series of tables that contains sales data, of which some of the fields need to be outputted to a webpage using C#. I've got the program pretty much built I just cannot figure out the correct SQL Query string to use to build a correct dataset to get what I need.

[This is my ERD structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDeqg.jpg)

From what I've been playing around with for the better part of the day I've found that essentially I need a dataset with stuff from the LineItem table, plus 'Description', 'UnitWeight', 'UnitPrice' from the Inventory table; 'Company' and 'addrBilling' from the Customer table; and 'OrderDate' from the Invoice table.

One of the strings I tried was this little testing one to see if I could get all the fields I wanted from just one of the InvoiceNum values. No luck. Output only displays multiples of all my data.

```
SELECT *
FROM customer JOIN lineitem JOIN inventory
WHERE lineitem.InvoiceNum = 2002;
```

This query was built from MS Access (which I have to use unfortunately). Access simply gives me a 'Type Mismatch in Expression'. Looked that up and found it could do with data types, but I've checked everything and any corresponding fields (like the two SKUs) have same data types.

```
SELECT LineItem.*,
   Customer.Company,
   Customer.addrBilling,
   Inventory.Description,
   Inventory.UnitWeight,
   Inventory.UnitPrice,
   Invoice.OrderDate,
   *
FROM (Customer INNER JOIN Invoice ON Customer.custNumber = Invoice.custNumber)
   INNER JOIN
   (Inventory INNER JOIN LineItem ON Inventory.SKU = LineItem.SKU)
      ON Invoice.InvoiceNumber = LineItem.InvoiceNumber;
```

And countless more that have all failed.

Hopefully some kind stranger can set me on the right path.

Thank you to anyone for any and all advice.

Comment: Your ERD structure doesn't have any direction in it; how can we know which is the one-side of the relationship, and which is the many side?

Comment: is it sql or ms-access

Comment: how you connect inventory to customer or invoice? the join is missing in this scenario

Comment: Your problem is in the syntax of an SQL statement against an Access database? All the other tags ([c#], [database-design], [database-schema]) are irrelevant.

Comment: Have you tried using the Access query editor to build your query? You can then switch to SQL view and use it in your program.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: (ERD structure) the Primary Key column is always the "one" side.

Comment: @Andre451 (ERD structure) If this image is from the MS Access Relationships window, it appears that the relationships are not enforcing referential integrity. If that is the case, then there may be different data types on the sides of the join, and the one-to-many is not enforced.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT LineItem.*,
    Customer.Company, Customer.addrBilling,
    Inventory.Description, Inventory.UnitWeight, Inventory.UnitPrice, Invoice.OrderDate
FROM ((Customer
INNER JOIN Invoice ON Customer.custNumber = Invoice.custNumber)
INNER JOIN LineItem ON Invoice.InvoiceNumber = LineItem.InvoiceNumber)
INNER JOIN Inventory Invoice.ItemId=Inventory.Id
```

In C#, you can wrap this in a multiline string literal:

```
var sql = @"
    SELECT LineItem.*,
        Customer.Company, Customer.addrBilling, ...
";
```

You should study the [INNER JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208854%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Since the OP's question is entirely about SQL syntax, then the answer should also be pure SQL (no C# string concatenation). At the very least, since the OP has indicated that this SQL statement is being used from C#, use a multiline string literal.

Comment: The question is tagged to c#, that' s why

Comment: Should it be? There is nothing about this question that is specifically C#; there isn't even any code relating to C#.

Comment: The last line is missing the `ON` keyword. `INNER JOIN Inventory ON Invoice.ItemId=Inventory.Id`

Answer (score -2):

Sooo....I'm an idiot. Looks like I was making this much harder than it needed to be. And, as it turns out, my first attempt was pretty much correct, I just left out a few things and did the order wrong.

Turns out my answer was:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer NATURAL JOIN Invoice NATURAL JOIN lineitem NATURAL JOIN inventory;
```

Nice and easy to make my dataset that contains unique tuples for each LineItem. Which I can read into my page.

My apologies for anybody's wasted time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Access SQL does not understand `NATURAL JOIN`: "Syntax error in FROM clause."